# Animating gridlayout from gone to visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Gridlayout (it is centered inside a relative layout)

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/ticketLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/pile"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >

<!-- some content -->
```

Now when I make it visible

```
ticketLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

it just appears, there is no animation at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you expected a animation? Animations aren't implicit.

Comment: android:animateLayoutChanges="true" is the attempt to enable animations here - but I think this has to go to the parent - but not sure yet - fighting a fight in a similar area at the moment ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to animate your `View`.
You can do it, for example, like this:

```
mticketLayout.setAlpha(0f);
mticketLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Animate the content view to 100% opacity, and clear any animation
// listener set on the view.
mticketLayout.animate()
        .alpha(1f)
        .setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration)
        .setListener(null);
```

Take a look at the Android Training: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no default animation for this. In order to achieve what you want I think you need to play an animation on the alpha property of your gridview.
Depending on what minimum API you want to support you can use the old animation system, or the new one, or even use NineOldAndroids.

The animateLayoutChange flag specifies that if you dynamically add a view inside this grid view, the system will have to play a default animation. (Most likely a fading effect) It doesn't help for the grid view itself.